# How to parse video timestamps in Go?

Tags: go, parsing, time

I am working on a project that has YAML like this

```
       - title: Toshiki Kadomatsu - Airport Lady                                                                                                          
         time: 35:46                                                                                                                                      
       - title: Yellow Magic Orchestra - Technopolis                                                                                                      
         time: 39:58
```

Specifically, it's a Go program to control MPD (Music Player Daemon) so that it can play specific songs in a long audio file. I've been getting by so far just getting the time value and using `mpc seek 35:46`.

However, I want to be able to show in my program the currently playing song in the mix. I was planning on doing this by receiving the elapsed time from MPD (expressed in number of seconds) [Ex: `1239.324`]. I can create a duration from this, just by tacking on a "s" on the end. I was then planning on comparing this duration to other durations from the songs in the yaml file.

I can't seem to parse `35:46` as a duration using `time.ParseDuration`. I could replace the `:` with a `m` and add a `s` at the end, but there are song files that go over an hour with timestamps like this: `01:04:20`.

How can I parse these timestamps with Go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strings.Split` method to separate a string based on a delimiter. Then, create a `[3]float64` array and fill in the data **from back to front**. This can avoid data shortages caused by missing hours or minutes.

```golang
arr := strings.Split(timeStr, ":")
var d [3]float64 // d[0]: hour, [1]: min, 0: sec
for i := 2; i >= 0; i-- {
    if len(arr) == 0 {
        break
    }
    val, err := strconv.Atoi(arr[len(arr)-1])
    if err != nil {
        return t, err
    }
    d[i] = float64(val)
    arr = arr[:len(arr)-1] // update arr
}
```

In addition, you can consider using time to handle some special cases, such as 71 seconds<sup>`00:01:11`</sup> . for example:

```golang
func ParseTime(timeStr string) (time.Time, error) {
    t := time.Date(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

    arr := strings.Split(timeStr, ":")
    var d [3]float64 // d[0]: hour, [1]: min, 0: sec
    for i := 2; i >= 0; i-- {
        if len(arr) == 0 {
            break
        }
        val, err := strconv.Atoi(arr[len(arr)-1])
        if err != nil {
            return t, err
        }
        d[i] = float64(val)
        arr = arr[:len(arr)-1] // update arr
    }

    var hours, minutes, seconds float64
    hours, minutes, seconds = d[0], d[1], d[2]
    if v := hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600; v >= 24 {
        return t, fmt.Errorf("[invalid hour] %s | %.4f", timeStr, v)
    }

    return t.Add(time.Duration(hours)*time.Hour + time.Duration(minutes)*time.Minute + time.Duration(seconds)*time.Second), nil
}
```

test

```
for _, timeStr := range []string{
        // ↓ general case
        "39",       // 0 0 39
        "2:7",      // 0 2 7
        "12:2:7",   // 12 2 7
        "23:59:59", // 23 59 59
        // ↓ advance
        "72",    //       1min 12sec
        "72:5",  // 1hour 12min 5sec
        "72:75", // 1hour 13min 15sec
        // ↓ error
        "24:00:00",
        "24:00:01",
        "23:61:00",
    } {
        myT, err := parseTime(timeStr)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println(myT.Hour(), myT.Minute(), myT.Second())
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
```

[image: Go Playground]